# Hide filter row in Agrid

Tags: ag-grid-angular, ag-grid

I am unable to hide floating filter row.

you would notice an empty line even though there are no filters enabled.

Demo at : https://plnkr.co/edit/6bGd5RHKuI9Th1cN

The Source of demo is same as default demo at https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-floating-filters/
with the only exception of below line added after the columnDefs variable declaration code, to hide the columns

```
this.columnDefs.forEach(c => (c.filter = false));
```

Or is it a Ag-grid issue?

Issue image:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Also found that setting the gridoptions.floatingfilter property = false cause this issue when you have set the floatingfilter property = true directly in the markup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per documentation: [Floating Filters](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-floating-filters/)

> - Floating Filters are an additional row under the column headers where the user will be able to see and optionally edit the filters associated to each column.
> - Floating filters depend on and coordinate with the main column filters.

Hence, when you set `[floatingFilter]="true"` at grid level, the additional row will be displayed. However, as you've set `filter = false` for every row, the row will remain empty.

If you'd like to hide the row, you'll have set the property as per this plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/AriPNpPsWs0zuISI

```
this.floatingFilter = false;
```

```
    <ag-grid-angular
      #agGrid
      ...
      [floatingFilter]="floatingFilter"
      ...
    ></ag-grid-angular>
```